# Прошу помощи в написание функции PHP

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте
в таблице MySQL есть три ячейки

```
js_core, js_plugins, js_app
```

в них хранятся имена js фалов через запятую, например:

```
в js_core = jquery,bootstrap
в js_plugins = pace,select2,uniform
в js_app = main,lessons
```

есть три папки /js/core, /js/plugins, /js/app

Сейчас я вывожу в цикле foreach каждую ячейку отдельно обрабатывая функцией explode().
Например:

```
<? foreach (explode(',', $section['js_core']) as $item): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/core/<?=$item?>.min.js"></script>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

и так я делаю 3 раза, меняется только путь к папкам.

помогите написать функцию которая бы объединила все три ячейки так же разбила строку по запятой и у каждого файла был правильный путь.

на выходе хочу получить вот такой результат:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/lessons.min.js"></script>
```

прошу помощи в реализации, так как сам не одолел задачу.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: объединение можна сделать при построение запроса в БД, вы используете прямые запросы в базу?

Comment: все запросы через ORM RedBeanPHP

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<? foreach ($section as $key => $value): ?>
<? foreach (explode(',', $value) as $item): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/<?=substr($key, 3)?>/<?=$item?>.min.js"></script>
<? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```